# Calculate the availability of a pod in kubernetes over a period of time

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, promql

I need to calculate the availability  of a pod in kubernetes over a period of time in percentage using PromQL.  Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to achieve it with below query:

> (sum_over_time((sum(kube_pod_status_ready{cluster="$cluster",condition="true", namespace="$namespace"}))[$availability_span:5m]))
>   /
>   (sum_over_time((sum(kube_pod_status_ready{cluster="$cluster",namespace="$namespace"}))[$availability_span:5m]))
>   * 100